# (ssh) Connection closed by

Tags: linux, ssh

unfortunately I don't have access to ssh server, I can only see:

```
Platform: i586-pc-linux-gnu
Compiled with: liblua-5.2.3 openssl-1.0.1k libpcre-8.35 libpcap-1.6.2 nmap-libdnet-1.12 ipv6
Compiled without:
Available nsock engines: epoll poll select

ssh -vvvl user ip

debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: first_kex_follows 0
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: reserved 0
debug2: mac_setup: setup hmac-sha1
debug1: kex: server->client 3des-cbc hmac-sha1 none
debug2: mac_setup: setup hmac-sha1
debug1: kex: client->server 3des-cbc hmac-sha1 none
debug2: bits set: 502/1024
debug1: sending SSH2_MSG_KEXDH_INIT
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEXDH_REPLY
Connection closed by IP
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should be solve adding:

```
MACs=hmac-sha1

ssh -o MACs=hmac-sha1 -vvvl user ip
```

Comment: explanation? what happens? what is missing, and how this answer solves the problem? ... please?

Comment: Its obviously the right answer in this situation but doesn't help anyone who wants to know why it works!!

Comment: The answer solves the problem because it forces the SSH client to use a specific Message Authentication Code (MAC) that is supported by the server. The option `-o MACs=hmac-sha1` sets the MAC to use a code base on SHA1 algorithm which is the one supported by the server (as can be seen via the `-vvvl` option). More infos at [this link](https://support.ssh.com/manuals/server-admin/44/Ciphers_and_MACs.html) best regards, *MrClick*